# Alternate links in a multilingual site Drupal 7

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual website currently on localhost. I want to add the alternate links to each page like this: rel="alternate" hreflang="x".
How do i do that? 
What about the canonical urls? I have already installed SEO suite module enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try [Menu attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module.

> This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.
>   The module currently allows you to set the following attributes for each menu item:
>    - Id
>    - Name
>    - Target
>    - Rel
>    - Class
>    - Style
>    - Accesskey

Comment: What happens when my main menu is a translatable block with my html code inside???

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Meta Tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module for canonical links.

> The Meta tags module allows you to automatically provide structured
>   metadata, aka "meta tags", about your website. In the context of
>   search engine optimization, when people refer to meta tags, they are
>   usually referring to the meta description tag and the meta keywords
>   tag that may help improve the rankings and display of your site in
>   search engine results.
>
> Meta tags have additional uses like the Open Graph Protocol used by
>   Facebook, specifying the canonical location of content across multiple
>   URLs or domains.

Comment: Hmm i see. Would i have to add the canonical url my self for each page and for each language? or this can be done automatically? Maybe using the clean urls i have already set up ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Internationalization contributions](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n_contrib) module says that it adds the `rel="alternative"` `hreflang="x"` to multilingual pages:

> Internationalization contributions is a set of modules that are add ons for [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module to provide compatibility with other contributed modules or some other features.